# Rotation Movement opengl c++

Tags: c++, opengl

Im trying to make a windmill using OpenGL. I want to make the blades of the fan rotate. How can i make it work.

Here is what i have so far for the fan part

```
void MyFan::drawWings()
{
GLboolean cullingIsOn;
glGetBooleanv(GL_CULL_FACE, &cullingIsOn);
glDisable(GL_CULL_FACE);
GLboolean normalizeIsOn;
glGetBooleanv(GL_NORMALIZE, &normalizeIsOn);
glEnable(GL_NORMALIZE);
glColor3f(5.5f, 3.0f, 5.5f);
glPushMatrix();
glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
glNormal3f( 1.0f, 0.0f, 2.0f);
glVertex3f( 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
glVertex3f( 0.0f, 4.0f, 0.0f);
glVertex3f(-2.0f, 4.0f, 1.0f);
glNormal3f( 0.0f, 1.0f, 2.0f);
glVertex3f( 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
glVertex3f(-4.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
glVertex3f(-4.0f,-2.0f, 1.0f);
glNormal3f(-1.0f, 0.0f, 2.0f);
glVertex3f( 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
glVertex3f( 0.0f,-4.0f, 0.0f);
glVertex3f( 2.0f,-4.0f, 1.0f);
glNormal3f( 0.0f,-1.0f, 2.0f);
glVertex3f( 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
glVertex3f( 4.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
glVertex3f( 4.0f, 2.0f, 1.0f);
glEnd();
glPopMatrix();
if (cullingIsOn==GL_TRUE) glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
if (normalizeIsOn==GL_TRUE) glEnable(GL_NORMALIZE);
}
void MyFan::tickTime(long int elapseTime) //elapsetime in milisec
{
};
```

Comment: Is this an assignment or homework of some sort? Did you write the code above yourself? Sorry, but the question seems to be a little odd, since you seem to know `glRotate` already - why don't you simply use this to make your fan rotate? Maybe you need to be more specific what your problem is.

Comment: its only a practice exercise. most of the codes was given. I'm totally new as i only know the basic so anything that will lead me further will be appreciated.

Comment: In this case, I would recommend looking at a basic tutorial like the "Legacy Tutorials" at http://nehe.gamedev.net/. SO is not the place to solve your excercises for you...

Comment: glBegin  and glEnd  are deprecated, instead you should be learning the modern pipeline approach (OpenGL 3.3+) - here is a good tut http://www.opengl-tutorial.org

Comment: @ScottStensland I totally agree with you, but since it seems to be a given exercise, I guess loorey has to stick with the legacy OpenGL, that's why I suggested NeHe. For OpenGL beginners in general, the tutorials you posted are of course much better.

Comment: @loorey : Id suggest having the center of the blades at (0,0,0) and then, after pushing the matrix, youll have to call glRotatef, and remember to call glPopMatrix after this.